# Custom google home action should always reconnect to get it working

Tags: google-home

i have a custom google home action implemented as described in the documentation (Oauth2 setup, sync, execute, etc... setup) and all works as expected on my Google home app and my google home physical devices.

Now, every now and then i need to reconnect the app in the Google Home App because it seems the app cannot reach my devices after some time. I checked my Oauth server if the refresh tokens are working ok and they do. Also my access token expires after 20 minutes and me reconnecting to the app should be done after some hours so the refreshing works in my opinion.

Now, are there any restrictions in using the TEST of the google home action?

The case i wrote is specific for personal use (intergration with personal server and domotica system) so i am actually not planning on releasing it, I just want to use it for myself. Is this allowed? Can i just leave my action in 'test' forever for such purposes?

**EDIT: 18/05/2022: custom actions still working flawlessly after 6 months in test :-)**

**EDIT: 02/02/2023: custom actions still working flawlessly in test :-)**

Additional question:
If i have to submit the app for release, i cannot meet the expectation in implementing state report as i have no control over the usage of buttons pressed at my home domotica. Is State Reporting also accepted when i report the state of my devices over time (let's say, every hour?)

tnx

EDIT:
So it seems there is something wrong with my refreshing of the tokens but i don't know what. When i try through postman, all works as expected, in stackdriver logs i see this :

```
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.accountlinking.type.AccountLinkingError"
errorReason: "Failed to get response from 3P. 3P returned malformed response like invalid response code or un-inflatble body."
request: {
body: "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REDACTED_VALUE&client_id=qbusauth&client_secret=REDACTED_VALUE"
method: "POST"
uri: "https://******.azurewebsites.net/token"
}
sessionId: -1039956344
step: "REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan to submit your Action for release, you'll just need to occasionally re-enable [device testing through the console](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing#enable-testing).

To minimize the number of query intents to your fulfillment, you should [implement Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) and proactively send device states to update HomeGraph. You would have to implement this if you decide to release your Action.

Comment: Tnx for your reply, do you have any idea on how long an action can stay in 'test' before i need to re-enable it? In case of not being ably to detect physical state changes, should a report state each hour or so be satisfying for google?

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact amount of time you can have a test agent running prior to needing to re-enable it. However, you will have to occasionally re-enable it - there is no way to keep a test agent running perpetually. 

For report state, if you believe your device states will change minimally in the hour, then 1x per hour is appropriate.